# Как выбрать N значений по N ключам из одной и той же таблицы-справочника без нескольких LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы:

1.Справочник `ref`:

```
+-----+-----------+
| id  |  text     |
|-----+-----------+
|  1  |  однажды  |
|  2  |  в        |
|  3  |  студеную |
|  4  |  зимнюю   |
|  5  |  пору     |
+-----+-----------+
```

2.Данные `main`:

```
+------+------+------+------+-----+
| fk1  | fk2  | fk3  | fk4  | fk5 |
+------+------+------+------+-----+
|  1   |  2   |  3   |  4   |  5  |
+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

**Чтобы получить строчку текста** из записи во второй таблице, где хранятся только коды слов можно сделать так

```
SELECT 
 table1.text as word1,
 table2.text as word2,
 table3.text as word3,
 table4.text as word4,
 table5.text as word5
FROM
 main
 left join ref as table1 on (fk1=table1.id)
 left join ref as table2 on (fk2=table2.id)
 left join ref as table3 on (fk3=table3.id)
 left join ref as table4 on (fk4=table4.id)
 left join ref as table5 on (fk5=table5.id);
```

И получить
`['однажды', 'в', 'студеную', 'зимнюю', 'пору']`

Но это не кажется очень правильным в моих условиях, где есть таблица объявлений `main` с несколькими полями-ключами `(marked_text_fk, main_text_fk)`, которые связаны с таблицей "текстовок" `(text_id, text_fulltext)`, потому что количество записей - 1 млн в первой таблице и 0.5 млн во второй.

Пожалуйста, подскажите есть ли **другие варианты запроса или разбивки данных на таблицы** с такими исходными условиями?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пятикратный `join` - вполне нормальное решение данной задачи в такой формулировке. (Кстати, почему вы делаете `left join`? Данные в таблицах что, могут быть несогласованны?)

Тут, на самом деле, странной выглядит сама схема БД. Почему в таблице `main` хранится пять ссылок одного типа? Их точно никогда не придется хранить шесть штук или четыре? Стоило бы сделать промежуточную таблицу-связку между `main` и `ref`, с полями `mainid`, `refid` и `order` (1 и 3е поля входят в первичный ключ).

Comment: В настоящем проекте изначально заложена простая структура: в таблице объявлений каждое поле соответствует полю объявления, например
в marked_text лежит выделенный кусок объявления
в main_text лежит основной текст объявления

но эти куски часто повторяются в разных объявлениях, поэтому в лоб было придумано хранить эти куски в отдельной таблице, а в основной - только их коды.
Вероятно, лучше сделать, как вы говорите, завести отдельную таблицу для связи объявление-поле-текстовка. Тогда не придется сочинять 4-5-6-кратные JOIN.

Comment: @AlexPanic Не факт, что лучше. Главное, отчётливо понимать, что пятикратный `join` - это цена за столь экзотическую схему БД. И нужно просто решить, что важнее - экзотическая схема или отсутствие многоэтажных `join`ов.

Answer (score 2):

Если сделать разумное допущение о том, что в таблице `main`, кроме полей с кодами слов, есть ещё и какой-нибудь первичный ключ... скажем, `id`, то задачу можно решить при помощи одного `join`'а и парочки хитрых трюков.

Сначала нужно размножить записи в таблице `main` таким образом, чтобы вместо одной их стало пять. У каждой должен быть свой номер и свой маппинг соответствующего поля с кодом в одно и то же поле. Затем нужно сделать обычный `join` со справочником. И, наконец, нужно применить трюк с использованием `case` вместо обычных средств для `pivot`-таблиц, которые начисто отсутствуют в mysql ввиду его полной ущербности.

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN text END) AS word1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN n = 2 THEN text END) AS word2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN n = 3 THEN text END) AS word3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN n = 4 THEN text END) AS word4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN n = 5 THEN text END) AS word5
FROM (
    SELECT id, 1 AS n, fk1 AS fk FROM main UNION
    SELECT id, 2 AS n, fk2 AS fk FROM main UNION
    SELECT id, 3 AS n, fk3 AS fk FROM main UNION
    SELECT id, 4 AS n, fk4 AS fk FROM main UNION
    SELECT id, 5 AS n, fk5 AS fk FROM main) view_of_main
JOIN ref ON (view_of_main.fk = ref.id)
GROUP BY view_of_main.id;
```

Вложенный запрос обозначен как `view_of_main` не случайно. Это как бы намекает на то, что его можно сделать вьюхой.

Comment: У меня получилось сделать запрос по вашей схеме! Гран мерси

Comment: @AlexPanic Само собой. Я же свой запрос протестил перед публикацией :) Но если планируете сохранить столь экзотическую структуру базы, то лучше переведите её, скажем, на PosgreSQL, в котором есть настоящие `cross`-таблицы.